# Why / has a wrong answer but // has a correct answer in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Run these two commands in Python:

```
print(int(822981260158260520/2))
print(int(822981260158260520//2))
```

The second one prints a correct answer but the first one does not. The difference is as big as 20. How did this happen? Is it a Python bug?

Comment: See this for more detail: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: The duplicate does not answer your question. The answer is that / is a float division while // is an int division that will only return the whole part (integer) of the result.